# babel-plugin-istanbul not following CSP directive, Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, babeljs, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, istanbul

I am getting the error `Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'"` while adding `babel-plugin-istanbul`  to a chrome extension which uses manifest v3 which doesn't allow eval function.

But, the package adds `var global = new Function("return this")()` to the `background.js` file. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Add `node: {global: false}` to your webpack config and simply use your own global like `var global = (function() { return this })()`

Comment: where should I add `var global = (function() { return this })()`, as this code is coming from the istanbuljs package?

Comment: Because their implementation is bad I suggest replacing it.

Comment: do you mean, should I create a new package that forks that package and replace the code?

Comment: I don't know. My advice is for manual configuration of webpack.